# Need to fetch second record in each case if entry is done more than once

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

Need to fetch the second record if entry of the pan is done more than once in sas enterprise guide

INPUT DATA:

```
PAN1 PREF1
PAN2 PREF1
PAN2 PREF2
PAN2 PREF3
PAN3 PREF3
PAN3 PREF4
```

OUTPUT:

```
PAN1 PREF1
PAN2 PREF2
PAN3 PREF4
```

So basically if the entry of the pan is once,then same record needs to be populated.
If the entry of the pan is more than once,then secord record of the pan needs to be populated.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Is this ordered by the second column?  If not, there is no "second" record.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `row_number()` with a window `count()`:

```
select pan, ref
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by pan order by ref) rn,
        count(*) over(partition by pan) cnt
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 2 or cnt = 1
```